# Why does Keras accept a batch size option for model.evaluate?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Why does the [`evaluate`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.2.0/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py#L958) function of the Keras API in Tensorflow accept a `batch_size`? To my knowledge, this parameter should only be relevant for managing how many samples we use per iteration during training. What influence does this choice have during model evaluation?

Answer (score 1):

Batch size is mainly used in Sequence-based predictions or in Time series predictions.

Below are the cases where you have to use batch size while prediction.

In `Time Series` use cases it may be desirable to use a large batch size when training the network and a batch size of 1 when making predictions in order to predict the next step in the sequence.

For `Stateful RNN` it is required to provide a fixed batch size during prediction/evaluation where the output state of the current batch is used as the initial state for the next batch. They keep information from one batch to another batch.

If your model doesn't fall into these kinds of category technically you don't need to provide `batch size` as input during evaluating. Even if you provide batch size, it's how much data you are feeding at a time for GPU.

Comment: Thanks, but what's the benefit if any of using a batch size **for prediction** larger than 1? And separately, if I understand what you wrote above correctly, the batch size for prediction really bears no relationship at all to the batch size in training, or what am I missing?